# Spring 3.1.0.RC1 - which maven repository?

Tags: spring, maven

As indicated on [springsource](http://www.springsource.org/) Spring 3.1.0.RC1 has just been made available for download. On the same site it is said that it is available from maven using http://maven.springframework.org/milestone. I'm not sure what this url is supposed to be but it does not appear to be a (valid) maven repository.

Also, the [Spring repository](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/) does not yet contain this version.

Anyone know if Spring 3.1.0.RC1 is available and in which maven repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The http://maven.springframework.org/milestone may not seem valid using HTTP browser, but it works.

Just do:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestone</id>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Tx, added http://maven.springframework.org/milestone to our Nexus and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

On this Spring [blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/09/18/maven-artifacts-2/) they say that "*The milestone and snapshot repositories are both hosted on Amazon's S3 service and as such the directory structure is not human-readable. To view the repositories in a human-readable format, use the S3Browse utility.*"

I haven't tried it myself yet, but this should work:

```
<repository>
   <id>spring-milestone</id>
   <name>Spring Portfolio Milestone Repository</name>
   <url>http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the repository browser at https://repo.springsource.org/webapp/artifactshome.html

Regards.